# How to setup java for dynamo db for first time?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to use **Dynamo DB**,

I want to know how to setup **pom.xml** like if I use maven what is dependency use for **dynamodb**

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>??</groupId>
      <artifactId>??</artifactId>
      <version>??</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
```

**or any example source code which I can research how to use it?**

For dynamodb and how to setup like list of table and create column one by one in dynamodb any source can i read ?

Comment: May help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use aws dynamo DB so you can use following code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.784</version>
</dependency>
```

you can use following example for setup by using below link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html

Answer (score 0):

Dependency in pom is:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Next if You want to use it in code You need to read about @DynamoDBTable .
Best lecture about it have of course [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-dynamodb)